# Calling 2 axios requests in 2 Vuejs components and sharing data using Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have 2 different components: Threads.vue and Posts.vue.

In Threads component there is a list of all threads and when clicking specific thread from the list it opens Posts.vue with listing all posts for that id_thread that is chosen in Threads.vue.

In **Threads component** there is a function that is called when user opens specific thread:

```
selectThread (val) {
    let threadObjectToChange = {
        id_thread: val,
        thread_name: "",
    };
    this.component_threads.forEach(thread => {
        if (thread.id === val) {
            threadObjectToChange.thread_name = thread.title;
        }
    });
    store.commit("changeSelectedThread", threadObjectToChange); // This is data of opened thread so I can use it in another component.
    let urlToFetch = "http://localhost:3005/posts/thread/" + val;
    axios.get(urlToFetch).then(function(response) {
        let newPostsList = response.data.data;
        if (newPostsList.length == 0) {
            let emptyArr = [];
            store.commit("changePosts", emptyArr);
            return 1;
        }
        let arrResponse = response.data.data;
        store.commit("changePosts", arrResponse);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
    })
    .then(function() {
        // always executed
    });
},
```

This works great, the Posts.vue gets all the data that is shared using Vuex.

The problem starts when I refresh Posts.vue and there is no data (I understand why). Then I added axios request under created method in Posts.vue to get all posts for that id_thread (stored in vuex from Threads.vue) inside component. That works when I refresh the page, but now request is called in both Threads.vue and in Posts.vue when I'm clicking thread.

The Posts.vue renders *faster* than vuex updating its store so in that component axios is sending id_thread NULL because that id of a thread is written in Threads.vue after clicking.

It's a little bit complex to describe. What I want is latest posts from my database when I open Posts.vue by clicking thread in Threads.vue and by refreshing Posts.vue but sending the request just one time in both cases!

What do you suggest, what is the best approach for this? I need to refresh posts array in Posts.vue when opening that component but updating thread id in vuex is *slow* so it's sending null as a id.

In **Posts.vue** axios request is similar, there under created method I'm sending:

```
let urlToFetch = "http://localhost:3005/posts/thread/" + store.state.selectedThread.id_thread;
```

Is there any way to wait for store state variable to update and then trigger component render? What is the best practice?

Comment: I suggest you to use components props. Define prop `thread` and pass it into Posts like `<posts :thread="thread.id"></posts>`. Now, you can access it in posts via `this.thread`.

Comment: I have two different views (ThreadsView.vue and PostsView.vue) where I import components with some extra and two different routes (/threads and /posts) where I plan to add later on parameters like /threads/:id or something. I think with using props I couldn't reach what I'm aiming for? Also aren't the props only available for passing data from parent to child components?

Comment: you can get the id from router. this.$route.params.id

Comment: @TEFO Yes, but I have similar problems in application and I would like to hear some more options about this. Really want to make this work using vuex (also for future tasks and projects).

Comment: but you dont have many options. when page reloads you have get data drom somewhere and pass it to vuex. either its route parameter or cookie. best option is get it from url because dont need to save it.

Comment: Yes, I see. I think I'll go with router parameters. Just one more thing, what do you think about storing ids and such data in local storage or something similar?